# How to put a space into a URL in curl using php's exec

Tags: php, unix, curl, exec

I'm using exec do a curl. The problem is that both this:

```
exec("curl --insecure https://site.com/?term=last day&x=1");
```

and

```
exec("curl --insecure https://site.com/?term=last%20day&x=1");
```

Give me an error because there's not an appropriate string in the "term" parameter. If I just go to https://site.com/?term=last day&x=1 it works fine but apparently %20 does not translate as a space on their end.

I think there's a problem with putting spaces into URLs in curl. What's the simplest way to do this right?

Comment: Why are you not using the [cURL functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php)?

Comment: Try using a `+` instead

Comment: You can do it in a browser because the browser encodes it properly *in the background*. cURL does not do such hand-holdery. Also, you can't have a space in a command argument like that.

Comment: Musa, thank you! I don't know why it didn't occur to me!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `escapeshellarg()`:

```
exec('curl --insecure ' . escapeshellarg($url));
```

`exec()` internally starts a shell and if you not escape characters properly the shell might expand meta chars like `&` in the string.